# how to setup subdomain in following environment: nginx, supervisor, django, gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a django app setup with nginx+gunicorn+supervisor and its working fine. But i need to create a subdomain for staging or development like "dev.domain.com". I have added another server block in nginx.conf for my subdomain. But my subdomain url was always pointing main domain site. so i changed the port no in proxy_pass as suggested on other posts. but due to gunicorn and supervisord i needed to add another conf file for this subdomain in "/etc/supervisord/conf.d/subdomain.conf" but when i reload supervisord its not able to start my subdomain program. below is my nginx.conf, subdomain.conf, script.sh:
**nginx.conf**

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip  on;
gzip_static  on;
gzip_types application/x-javascript text/css text/html application/json text/css text/json;

server {
listen   80;
server_name domain_name
# no security problem here, since / is alway passed to upstream
root /home/path/to/project/base
# serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles
location /static/ {
    # if asset versioning is used
    if ($query_string) {
        expires max;
    }
    autoindex off;
    root /home/path/to/static/;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
}

server {
listen   80;
server_name subdomain_name
# no security problem here, since / is alway passed to upstream
root /home/path/to/subdomain_directory(which is different, you can say it is fully differnt project which i want to run as development project);
# serve directly - analogous for static/staticfiles


location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
}
}
```

**script.sh**

```
set -e
NUM_WORKERS=4
# user/group to run as
USER=user_name
#GROUP=your_unix_group
cd /home/path/to/subdomain_base
source subdomain_virtualenv_activation
LOGFILE=log_file_path
LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
exec virtualenvironment/bin/gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --log-level=debug \
--log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

**subdomain.conf**

```
[program:programname]
directory = /home/path/to/subdomainbase/
user = user_name
command = /home/path/to/script.sh
stdout_logfile = /home/path/to/log
stderr_logfile = /home/path/to/log
```

I have a procfile too as suggested in gunicorn which is in base directory
**Procfile**

```
./manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Ok so these are my configurations. Please check where i am doing the wrong thing. I just want to run my development server as a different project but under same domain as subdomain. after all this whatever changes i am doing, main domain is working fine wioth the same process. Please let me know if you need more info on this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I am reading again your post, and... Should not you must set ADDRESS in your gunicorn script? gunicorn by default uses port 8000, maybe your subdomain is trying to use the same port?

**END EDIT**

I have two Django applications running with nginx, gunicorn and supervisor as you want to do (well, not the same, but very similar, i have two domains and a subdomain). I don't see where is your mistake, I think must be in nginx configuration. Maybe the "root" line?

Have you seen if supervisord returns you an error when you try to start it using "supervisorctl" command?

I can show you my configuration and you can compare it:

I have two .conf files for **nginx**:

domain1.conf:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  domain1.net;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain1.net$request_uri;    
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain1.net;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.log;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/domain1/media/;
        autoindex on;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }

}
```

and domain2.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain2.es;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.log;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/dev/domain2/domain2/static/;
        autoindex on;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8005/;
    }

}
```

My two **gunicor scripts** are the same, just changing paths and ADDRESS in one of them:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/domain1.log
LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
NUM_WORKERS=1
# user/group to run as
USER=user
GROUP=user
ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:8005
cd /var/www/dev/domain1
source /path/to/venv/domain1/bin/activate
test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
exec gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS --bind=$ADDRESS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

My two **supervisor** scripts are the same too:

```
[program:domain1]
directory = /var/www/dev/domain1/
user = user
command = /path/to/bin/gunicorn_domain1.sh
stdout_logfile = /var/log/nginx/domain1.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/nginx/domain1.log
```

I hope you found this helpful.

Comment: thanks for reply, i have tried adding "ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:PORT" in gunicorn script and reloaded the supervisord, But it didn't work. I checked the supervisor log, there are two messages related to my new subdomain app 1. EXIT STATUS 1: NOT EXPECTED and in the next line 2."entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly" ( I don't know why it is saying too many restarts i have only reloaded once. Please check if you can get what is causing the problem, thanks.

Comment: If you run the script by hand (without supervisord), does it work correctly?

Comment: Oh, can we do that to test? I will test likewise and let you know if it is working or not, thanks for replying.

Comment: Hey, I just ran the script, and it was giving error for permission, after i give permission, script ran and just give me prompt again, what do you think it will work now. I will try again and integrate with nginx, hope this will work. Thanks.

Comment: But one problem i see, when checked gunicorn log, error is "connection  in use, trying to connect 127.0.0.1:8000". And i have given address in script as "localhost:8080". Port is different still it is trying to connect to port 8000. Please check what could be the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help jjimenez, i forgot to add "--bind=$ADDRESS" in script. Now the processes are running fine.

Comment: By the way... don't forget to accept the answer if you think that resolved your problem ;)